# Downloading .png with Shiny app not working

Tags: r, shiny, download, png, choropleth

I made a script to make a coropletic map. I tried adding a button to download the map in png format but it doesn't work. When I press the button a .htm file is downloaded, moreover the file name does not match what I have set.

I have tried using the app from RStudio, Chrome and Edge, but the result is the same.

The map downloading part is as follows:

```
output$download_map <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("mappa", Sys.Date(), ".png", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      png(file=file)
      plot(output$map())
      dev.off()
    }
  )
```

Below is all the code for reference:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("The mapper"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("csv_url", "URL file CSV", 
                value = "..."),
      textInput("separator", "Separator", value = ";"),
      actionButton("submit_csv", "Submit CSV"),
      selectInput("shp_file", "Shapefile",
                  choices = c(
                    "A 2023" = file.path(getwd(), "Shape Files", "A 2023", "A.shp"),
                    "B 2013" = file.path(getwd(), "Shape Files", "B 2013", "B.shp"), 
                    "C 2003" = file.path(getwd(), "Shape Files", "C 2003", "C.shp")
                  )
      ),
      selectInput("column", "Select column", choices = NULL),
      actionButton("submit_map", "Submit map"),
      downloadButton("download_map", "Download map")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("map")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- eventReactive(input$submit_csv, {
    if (input$csv_url != "") {
      read.csv(input$csv_url, sep = input$separator)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(data(), {
    updateSelectInput(session, "column", choices = names(data()))
  })
  
  shp_path <- eventReactive(input$submit_map, {
    input$shp_file
  })
  
  output$map <- renderPlot({
    req(data())
    req(input$column)
    req(shp_path())
    
    comuni_sf <- st_read(shp_path())
    
    comuni_sf <- st_transform(comuni_sf, crs = 4326)
    
    comuni_sf <- merge(comuni_sf, data(), by.x = "COD_ISTAT", by.y = "COD_ISTAT")
    
    variabile <- input$column
    
    comuni_sf[[variabile]] <- as.numeric(comuni_sf[[variabile]])
    
    pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Greens", domain = comuni_sf[[variabile]])
    
    ggplot(comuni_sf) +
      geom_sf(aes(fill = get(variabile))) +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colours = pal(seq(min(comuni_sf[[variabile]]), max(comuni_sf[[variabile]]), length.out = 5))) +
      theme_void()
  })
  
  output$download_map <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("mappa", Sys.Date(), ".png", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      png(file=file)
      plot(output$map())
      dev.off()
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If anyone can give me a hand I will be very grateful.

Comment: First create a reactive map object, say, named mapa.  Then display it in `output$map  <- renderPlot(mapa())` and/or download it.